# html cache-control=no-cache changes to cache-control=max-age=0

Tags: html, http-headers, cache-control

I've built a simple page to test the cache-control and I'm getting confused by the results.
The page is just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Website teste</title>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello World</div>

    <script>
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload()
        }, 10000)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I do a hard-refresh the cache-control is what expected
[image]

but the next refresh the cache-control changes to max-age=0

[image]

And shouldn't the result be a 304 (Not Modified) instead a 200 (OK)

This sample site is running on VisualStudio (IIS)

Comment: The header value you write in the HTML page is not the same as the real HTTP header. It is just "http equivalent", hence `http-equiv`. Your server does not scan your html page to set the header. The real header sent is what you see in the debug panel.

Comment: So, that means this <meta> is worthless?

Comment: Yes, it is more of a suggestion as far as I understand it. Ah, see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http-equiv` attribute of the `meta` element is defined in the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#pragma-directives). Note that:

> The `http-equiv` attribute is an enumerated attribute. The following table lists the keywords defined for this attribute...

`cache-control` is not one of the listed values, and thus this directive has no effect.

Your assumption isn't unreasonable, though; in earlier versions of the standard [it was suggested](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1866#section-5.2.5) that servers could create headers based on this element:

> HTTP servers may read the content of the document `<HEAD>` to generate
> header fields corresponding to any elements defining a value for the
> attribute `HTTP-EQUIV`. NOTE - The method by which the server extracts document meta-information is unspecified and not mandatory.

I have no idea whether any servers actually did this, though.

Finally, note that the `Cache-Control` header you're looking at in the developer tools is a *request* header, not a *response* header, and thus has nothing to do with any of this. It's something that browsers often add to the request on refresh to make sure they don't get served cached content.